# fatal: could not unset 'remote.origin.url'

Tags: git

I've observed that my Git repository has two remotes for origin because when I run this:

```
git config --get-regexp 'remote\\.origin\\..*'
```

I get two results:

```
remote.origin.url https://user:password@my-repo:7990
remote.origin.url http://my-repo.com:7990/scm/my-project.git
```

However, I fail to delete either of them. For instance, if I try to delete the first one, like this:

```
git remote set-url --delete origin https://user:password@my-repo:7990
```

I get:

```
fatal: could not unset 'remote.origin.url'
```

Any idea why this error appears?

Comment: Maybe this is set in different config files and git is failing to edit one of them. You could manually edit those files and remove one of the entries.

Comment: The only config file that I know of is in `.git/config` and that only contains one address. Any idea where there could be another config file?

Comment: Yeah, there are four places for configurations. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17756808/2883579).

Comment: And you can also run `git config --list --show-origin` to see from which file the values come from.

Comment: Thanks. That actually did it. I realised I had some redundant configuration in my home folder that was mixing things up.

Answer (score 10):

You can remove the remote `origin` then add again.

```
$ git remote rm origin                   # remove a first remote
$ git remote -v

# if you see your second origin
$ git remote rm origin                   # remove the second origin

$ git remote add origin <repo-url>       # add new origin

$ git remote -v                          # see all the remotes you have
```

Comment: Firstly, this doesn't work. You need to use `add` instead of `set-url`. Secondly, even if try with `add`, I get `fatal: remote origin already exists` because the origin has two URLs pointing to it and only the first one is deleted with `rm`.

Comment: @octavian, yes `set-url` should be `add`. Try removing  `origin` for two times. See if it works!

Answer (score 3):

If it is a **remote** added with `--push` option you have to use `--push` option again to delete the remote like this:

```
git remote set-url --delete --push <remote_name> <remote_url_to_delete>
```

This will only delete the URL, not the remote.

---

I was having the same issue with a pushable remote added with `--add --push` option like this:

```
git remote set-url --add --push <remote_name> <remote_url>
```

This is usually made to have diferent URLs to the same remote to push changes faster to diferent places.

If you would like to do that, after adding the URLs you just have to use:

```
git push <remote> <branch>
```

And it will push to every URL added to your **remote**

Answer (score 0):

git unset-all remote.origin.push

Comment: This command doesn't exist, from what I can find.