# How can I remove two origin lines of my git settings?

Tags: git

I made a mess of my git settings.
When I check my remote settings with

```
git remote -v
```

I get

```
origin  https://cx1964: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@github.com/cx1964/home_claude_bin_scripts.git (fetch)
origin  https://cx1964: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@github.com/cx1964/home_claude_bin_scripts.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/cx1964/cx1964Repos_fastAPI_React_Redis.git (push)
```

But I want

```
origin  https://github.com/cx1964/cx1964Repos_fastAPI_React_Redis.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/cx1964/cx1964Repos_fastAPI_React_Redis.git (push)
```

**How can I achieve this?**

Comment: Use [`git remote set-url`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) to manage the remotes.

Comment: @user2588998 It seems to me like your repo is in a weird state. I would tackle this by manually editing `.git/config`, or at least inspecting it. You might need to clean up what appears under `[remote "origin"]` in there.

Comment: In fact, it might be helpful if you add to the question what appears under `[remote "origin"]` in that repo's `.git/config` file, it's likely to be informative.

Answer (score 0):

`git remote remove origin` to delete your current origin remote then recreate it with

`git remote add origin https://github.com/cx1964/cx1964Repos_fastAPI_React_Redis.git`

you can also change the remote url with

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/cx1964/cx1964Repos_fastAPI_React_Redis.git
```

Comment: When I use   **git remote remove origin**  and  **git remote add origin github.com/cx1964/cx1964Repos_fastAPI_React_Redis.git**   I still get  **origin cx1964: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@github.com/… (fetch)**   **origin cx1964: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@github.com/… (push)**  **origin github.com/cx1964/cx1964Repos_fastAPI_React_Redis.git (push)**   When I use   **git remote -v**

Comment: Do I have to provide more information to fix it?

Comment: Did you try with `git remote set-url` ?

Comment: yes. When I two times use **git remote set-url --delete origin <uri>. I get at the second time the error **fatal: could not unset 'remote.origin.url'**

Comment: **git remote -v** gives two line, but with wrong urls

Comment: I want the url **https://github.com/cx1964/cx1964Repos_fastAPI_React_Redis.git**

Comment: It seems that someone had a similar issue try to check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981272/fatal-could-not-unset-remote-origin-url)

Comment: Sorry that link does does not fix the problem. I think there something more going on (see my new  problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71816377/how-can-i-repair-my-git-to-clone-a-repro) .