# How can I repair my git to clone a repro?

Tags: authentication, github

Since a few days, I can not clone my git repro on my Linux machine (Ubuntu 20.04).
Although when I try to clone this same git repro on a other Linux machine I can succesfully clone the repro. Wheb I try it on my Windows machine I also could clone the repro succesfully.

When I try to clone I get the following messages:
Cloning into 'home_claude_linux_bin_scripts'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/cx1964/home_claude_bin_scripts.git/' not found

Is a private git repro.
But I also tried to clone a public repro and got on the machine the same errors, and on the other linux machine and the Windows machine, again I could succesfully clone the repro.

What are the steps to fix this problem?

Comment: Please stop saying "repro".

Comment: The remote repository either doesn't exist or it is private. If it is private you need authorization. On this machine you don't have authorization. Note that Git does not do authorization; this is not a Git question at all. It is probably not even a programming problem so it doesn't belong on this site.

Comment: It is a private repository. Which steps do I have to take to do authorization on my machine?

Comment: https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication

Comment: I already have created an Personal access tokens. This is what I used on the working Linux and Windows machines. But this does not help when I want to clone it on my other machine. I still get the messages: Cloning into 'home_claude_linux_bin_scripts'... remote: Repository not found. fatal: repository 'https://github.com/cx1964/home_claude_bin_scripts.git/' not found. What can I still do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by cleaning up my ~/.gitconfig file.
I now only use

```
[user]
      email = <my email>
      name  = <my git name>
[push]
      default = simple
[core]
      editor = code --wait
      autocrlf = false
[credential]
      credentialStore = secretservice
[init]
      defaultBranch = main
```