# If I use multiple remote repositories (Github and BitBucket), will other collaborators know?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I'm looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12961543/2056180) response to set up multiple remote repositories.

If I work with collaborators on BitBucket, is there a way of them knowing I have it set up with Github as well? Or is that only known to me locally?

I don't want to cause collaborators any confusion. If I rename the remotes will it be renamed for them too?

For ethical concerns, this is for a class project that I also want to be tracked on my Github for later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I work with collaborators on BitBucket, is there a way of them knowing I have it set up with Github as well?

Mostly no, though there is a chance of information leak. If you pull with merge from a remote the name or URL of the remote could be added to the commit message. You should always verify what you merge and what you push.

> Or is that only known to me locally?

Mostly yes (except for automatic merge above). When pull and push git operates on objects from its database (commits, trees, files and annotated tags) that aren't assigned to remotes and don't store information about remotes. Git also fetches/pushes references (branches and lightweight tags) that also don't contain information about remotes.

Information about remotes is stored in your local `.git/config` but it's never pulled or pushed. Until you add a copy of it to the repo and push so you have to avoid that.

> I don't want to cause collaborators any confusion. If I rename the remotes will it be renamed for them too?

No, their remotes are theirs.